# My /dev/sda5 (mounted at /) is full, and find /opt/intel takes most space. How can I clean it?

Tags: intel, disk, disk-usage

I'm trying to upgrade the system by do-release-upgrade, and get that there are not enough space. I've deleted the unused linux headers and run apt-get autoremove.

Here are the detailed folder size information:

```
/opt/intel$ sudo du --max-depth=2 --human-readable /opt/ | sort --human-numeric-sort
4.0K    /opt/containerd/bin
4.0K    /opt/containerd/lib
4.0K    /opt/intel/bin
8.0K    /opt/intel/impi
12K     /opt/containerd
16K     /opt/intel/imb
16K     /opt/intel/performance_snapshots_2018.2.0.551022
16K     /opt/intel/performance_snapshots_2019.1.0.579888
16K     /opt/intel/samples_2018
16K     /opt/intel/samples_2019
20K     /opt/intel/licenses
136K    /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019
156K    /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018
656K    /opt/intel/ide_support_2018
892K    /opt/intel/ide_support_2019
4.1M    /opt/intel/.scripts
6.2M    /opt/intel/.pset
19M     /opt/intel/documentation_2019
28M     /opt/intel/documentation_2018
40M     /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2018.2.046
40M     /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2019.1.053
43M     /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2019.5.075
81M     /opt/intel/ism
120M    /opt/intel/debugger_2019
181M    /opt/intel/debugger_2018
233M    /opt/intel/clck
288M    /opt/intel/inspector_2018.2.0.551023
306M    /opt/intel/inspector_2019.1.0.579146
545M    /opt/intel/conda_channel
636M    /opt/intel/advisor_2018.2.0.551025
682M    /opt/intel/itac
785M    /opt/intel/advisor_2019.1.0.579143
795M    /opt/intel/intelpython2
919M    /opt/intel/vtune_amplifier_2018.2.0.551022
960M    /opt/intel/intelpython3
1.7G    /opt/intel/vtune_amplifier_2019.1.0.579888
9.7G    /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144
9.8G    /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.5.281
11G     /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199
39G     /opt/
39G     /opt/intel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have installed 3 different versions of Intel Parallel Studio XE - version 2018.2, 2019.1 and 2019.5. The libraries of each version take up 10-11 GB of disk space.

Remove those applications, using the recommended uninstall method. According to the [documentation](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/parallel-studio-xe-2019-install-guide-linux.html) (on page 15), this is the uninstall step:

> #### 6 Uninstalling the Product
>
> To uninstall the Intel® Parallel Studio XE on Linux* OS, use the shell
> scripts `uninstall.sh` or `uninstall_GUI.sh` located at: 
> `<install-dir>/parallel_studio_xe_2019.x.xxx` 
> After invoking this
> script, follow the prompts for the uninstall process

If you believe the applications are already uninstalled, and it is a case of the uninstall script not cleaning up properly, you can simply remove the folder `/opt/intel` (as this is not a standard part of Ubuntu).

*Warning: The following command is a destructive and irreversible procedure, run only if you're sure this is what you want:*

```
sudo rm -R /opt/intel/
```

After these products have been removed, you'll gain 39 GB of disk space. Even if you leave only the latest version installed (2019.5), you'll free up over 25 GB of space.